# What is the use of dbcontext generator in EF 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a MVC project that use Entity Framework 6. I am puzzled as how it is created. Because there is no .edmx file, I guess it must be created as EF 6.x dbcontext generator. So what does dbcontext generator do? Does it create database from the model? If so, how to create database in the model? May I modify the database later and update the model? What are changed in the sources? Thanks.

Comment: The Entity Framework approach that doesn't use edmx file is the Code First approach, basically you define your Model Classes (POCO), create your DbContext, run some EF DB migrations command (e.g. update-database) and then EF will automatically generate a Database for you based on the Models that you've created. Alternatively it can be reversed engineered from an existing Database using the Entity Framework Tools for Visual Studio, check out [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200620.aspx)

Comment: What will I post? I think you should check the link I've provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to understand everything you're saying, but it sounds like you have a project which uses the "Code First" approach. There is no .edmx file in this approach. Entity Framework Code First can be used with both new (see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj193542.aspx) and existing databases (see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200620.aspx) and with regards to updating it, you could either manually modify the database or you could look into something called "Code First Migrations" (see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx), which allows you to add/remove tables and fields via code.

Comment: For Code First approach, there is no .edmx file because database is not yet available, right?

Comment: @user585440, no.. there is no edmx because edmx is only used in the "Design First" approach. You don't actually need edmx files at all anymore; instead the idea of Code First is the database is generated from your classes (model) instead. You can still use edmx/designer approach with EF6 if you want instead of CodeFirst... example can be found here: https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/creating-the-web-application